# After IE driver is disposed, IEDriverServer.exe process still hanging

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer-8, webdriver

I'm using Selenium's IE driver for web testing. After launching IE8 and closing it, the `IEDriverServer.exe` process doesn't go away. If I run the test again, a new process gets created and keeps hanging. What is wrong with my test code or Selenium setup?

```
using (var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(
    new InternetExplorerOptions() { 
        IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true }))
{
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
    driver.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of the Selenium WebDriver .NET bindings are you running? The semantics of the .NET InternetExplorerDriver class's `.Dispose()` method in 2.25 or earlier are not equivalent to calling the `.Quit()` method. This means that to correctly shut down the IEDriverServer.exe process in versions 2.25 or earlier of the .NET bindings, you have to explicitly call the `.Quit()` method. It should be noted that with the yet-to-be-released 2.26 version of the .NET bindings, this has changed, and calling `.Dispose()` will be equivalent to calling `.Quit()`, whether called explicitly or implicitly via the `using` construct.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified :
.Quit()  -->  close driver and browser
.Close() -->  close browser
.Dispose()->  Don't know